# ggplot does not display density curve correctly when changing xlim and ylim

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1e6, sd = 0.01))
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = x)) + geom_density() + ylim(0, 1) + xlim(-5, 5)
```

[image]

A considerable part of the density-curve for ~ density > 0.2 is missing.

Does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `coord_cartesian` to keep all the underlying data points:

```r
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1e6, sd = 0.01))
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = x)) + geom_density() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-5, 5), ylim = c(0, 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>